# React dropdown issue - how to stop dynamically created dropdowns from all updating at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, react-hooks, dropdown

I am dynamically rendering a large list of cards using `React` hooks, and each component has its drop-down list. If I select one option, which updates the component state, every drop-down update to the same value. I have tried implementing select an option of `React`, and separately React-dropdown, and none of my approaches work. I recognize the problem is that when any dropdown is updated, they all refer to the same value in state and if I comment out the state update the dropdowns work.

I just don’t capture the state update. I am unsure what is the best way to capture these selection(s) while the user picks between the dropdowns and then showing the rendered selection.

A lot of the approaches I have seen don’t address having multiple dynamically created dropdowns on one page, so if there are any thoughts on how to resolve the issue, that would be helpful. Below is part of the code:

```html
<select onChange(event=> selectedDropdownItem(selection)
  value={event.target.value}
  >
  dropdownList.map(name =>
  <option key={name.id} value={name.id} label={name.name} />
</select>
```

```js
const [header, setHeader] = useState({ name: “select name”, id: null })

selectedDropdownItem = selection => {
  setHeader({
    name: selection.name,
    id: selection.id
  })
}
```

Comment: At the very least, you need to have separate variables for keeping track of each dropdown.

Comment: Hi Yevgen, thanks for replying. Could you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

As i am not much clear about your question for the multiple selection in single component. I just created one which will do the dynamic dropdown based on that, and update the name based on selection using `useState`. Whenever you do the selection , it will come to parent component and do the update and return the value to the child component.
Hope i explained as you expected.

Here is the working code [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-multi-dropdown-select?file=Hello.js).

If you have any queries, give a comment :)

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';

    const DropDownCard = ({name, list, selectedValue, onChange}) => {

      const onSelectChange = event => {
        const { value } = event.target;
        const { name } = list.find(val => val.id == value);
        onChange({id: value, name});
      };

        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Card {name}</h1>
            <select onChange={onSelectChange} value={selectedValue}>
             {
               list.map(name => <option
                key={name.id}
                value={name.id}
                label={name.name}
              />)
             }

            </select>
          </div>
        )
    }

    const cardList = [
      {name:'', selectedValue: null},
      {name:'', selectedValue: null},
      {name:'', selectedValue: null},
    ];

    const Home = () => {
      const [hea, setHea] = useState(cardList);
      const list = [
        {name: "select name", id: ''},
        {name: "Name 1", id: 1},
        {name: "Name 2", id: 2}
      ];

      const onCardNameSelect = (info, index) => {
        setHea(prevState => {
          const {id, name} = info;
          prevState[index].selectedValue = id;
          prevState[index].name = name;
          return [...prevState];
        });
      };

      return(
        <>
          <div>Hello</div>
          {hea.map((val,i) => <DropDownCard  key={"dropDown"+Math.random()}
            name={val.name}
            selectedValue={val.selectedValue}
            list = {list}
            onChange = {event => onCardNameSelect(event, i)}
          />)}
        </>

      )
    };
    export default Home;
```

Comment: Thanks, Raj. This works for me. One question though - about the arrays 'list' and 'cardList' - in this case you have defined them to be 3 exactly. How would this approach be different if that number was really large or unknown until the get request?

Comment: It will work even you pass as much array of object as u want. In my example, if you add more filelds also, it will work. try to update and validate it [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-multi-dropdown-select?file=Hello.js)